# npm: Install packages for multiple cpus

Tags: node.js, sass, npm-install, node-sass

We're using NPM to manage our dependencies. We also commit our node_modules folder to source control because we don't want our buildserver to depend on [npmjs.com](http://npmjs.com).

We started using [sass](http://sass-lang.com) and this uses node-sass, which needs a compiled version of libsass to run. When doing `npm install node-sass`, npm will download bindings for your current os and cpu.

However, our development machines are x64 and the buildserver is x32. Since we commit our node_modules, the x64 version of the node-sass bindings won't run on the buildserver.

Is there a way to tell npm to get multiple versions of the bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can create the folders manually and download the binding.node files from the GitHub Releases page.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly how we 'fixed' this. However, updating packages will be a pain.

Comment: This answer would be so much more useful with a hyperlink to the releases page in question :)